# Check ModelState in action filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter, modelstate

Can I check `ModelState.IsValid` in my custom action filter in `OnActionExecuting` method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  ModelState is part ViewData.  So you can get it using:

```
filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState
```

For example, if you wanted to inject some code after the action executes, but only if `ModelState.IsValid == true`, you can do:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    if (!filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) return;
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks... funny how missing a simple thing like ModelState being a part of ViewData can be so annoying. This also works from the View!

Comment: It will, ViewData is nothing if not for the View.